# Prove congruence using fermat's thm

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I was given this problem (I have to prove) and not sure if I use fermat's theorem 
$24^{31} ≡ 23^{32} (mod 19)$

If I do use fermat's is this right:

I would do the LHS first:

$24^{18}·24^{13} ≡ 1·24·24^{12}$

RHS:

$23^{18}·23^{14} ≡ 1·23^{14}$

I am not sure where to from here or if it is correct thus far. I have looked at some other posts but they have not helped with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin with reducing $24$  and $23$ mod. 19. Little Fermat asserts that non zero elements  have order a divisor of $18$, i.e., it can be $1, 2, 3, 6, 9$ or $18$.

Let's do the computations:
$$24^{31}=5^{31\bmod 18}=5^{13}, \qquad 23^{32}=4^{32}=2^{64\bmod 18}=2^{10}.$$

Now, modulo $19$:
$$5^{2}\equiv 6, \,5^3\equiv 30=11, \,5^6\equiv 121\equiv 7,\,5^9\equiv 76\equiv 1$$
 Thus $5$ has order $9$, and $24^{31}\equiv 5^{13}\equiv 5^4\equiv 36\equiv -2 \mod 19$.

As for the right-hand side:
$$2^3\equiv 8, \,2^6\equiv 64\equiv 7, 2^9\equiv 56\equiv -1,$$
hence $ 23^{32}\equiv 2^{10}\equiv -2 \mod 19$.

Answer (score 2):

So far, so good.
A couple of simplifications might help make further progress.

- Rewrite 23 and 24 as 4 and 5 mod 19, respectively.
- Now you can rewrite $4 = 2^2$, so that $4^{14} = 2^{28} = 2^{10} \mod 19$.
- A similar simplification might be $5^{12} = 25^6 = 6^6 \mod 19$.

Proceeding along these lines should make the computation reasonable.

Comment: How come you are allowed to write $4 mod 19$ and $5 mod 19$, I understand that they are remainders, I just want to know why it is allowed. This is all new to me.

Comment: For any two numbers $a,b$ such that $19$ divides the difference $a-b$, you have that $a = b \mod 19$.

Comment: ok, I knew that. $19|1$

so how did you get the second part of your answer

Answer (score 2):

As $126$ is equal to $18\cdot 7$ and $19-1=18$ we have:
$$\color{#0a0}{23\equiv 2^2}\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#0a0}{23}^{31+32}\equiv \color{#0a0}{23}^{63}\equiv (\color{#0a0}{2^2})^{63}\equiv 2^{2\cdot 9\cdot 7}\equiv (\color{#c00}{2^{18}})^7\equiv \color{#c00}1^7\equiv 1\mod 19 $$

Now we multiply both side by $24^{31}$ to get 
$$24^{31}\cdot 23^{31+32}\equiv (24.23)^{31}23^{32}\equiv 24^{31}\mod 19$$
 and because $24.23\equiv 5\cdot 4 \equiv 1 \mod 19$ we conclude $23^{32}\equiv 24^{31}\mod 19 $

Comment: Clear to you and I, but not necessarily a beginner! Glad to see the elaboration.

Comment: @BillDubuque where did $126$ come from? I am so confused

Comment: $23\equiv 4\mod 19$ and $31+32=63$ and $4^{63}\equiv 2^{126}$

Comment: @Csci319 $\,\ \color{#0a0}{23\equiv 2^2}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{23}^{63}\equiv (\color{#0a0}{2^2})^{63}\equiv 2^{2\cdot 9\cdot 7}\equiv (\color{#c00}{2^{18}})^7\equiv \color{#c00}1^7\equiv 1\ $ by $\rm\color{#c00}{Fermat}\ $ Elaqqad: Please feel welcome to use that if you like (click on it to get the TeX) $\ \ $

Comment: ok I see, because  $23≡4 (mod19)$  And then why do you add the exponents?

Comment: $\begin{align}23\equiv 4\\ 24\equiv 5\end{align}\ $ so $\ 23^{32}\equiv 24^{31}\!\!\iff 4^{32}\equiv \color{#c00}{5}^{31}\equiv \color{#c00}4^{\color{#c00}-31}\,$ by $\, \color{#c00}{5\equiv 4^{-1}},\,$ by  $\,5\cdot 4\equiv 1\,$ $\tag*{}$   
Finally $\ 4^{32}\equiv 4^{-31}\!\!\iff 4^{32+31}\equiv 1,\,$ by multiplying both sides by $\,4^{31}\ \ $ @Csci319

Answer (score 1):

As $23\equiv4,32\equiv14\pmod{19-1}$

Using Fermat's Little Theorem, $23^{32}\equiv4^{14}$

which $\equiv2^{28}\equiv2^{10}\pmod{19}$

Similarly, $24^{31}\equiv5^{13}\pmod{19}$

$5^3\equiv-8\pmod{19}\implies5^{12}\equiv(-8)^4\equiv8^4$

$8^4=(2^3)^4=2^{12}$

Now $24^{31}-23^{32}\equiv5\cdot2^{12}-2^{10}=2^{10}(5\cdot2^2-1)\equiv?\pmod{19}$

Answer (score 0):

Start from (all work is mod 19)
$$ 7^3 \equiv 49\cdot 7 \equiv 11\cdot 7 \equiv 77 \equiv 1 \\
4^3 \equiv 64 \equiv 7 \Rightarrow 4^9 \equiv 1 \\
4^{27} \equiv (4^9)^3 \equiv 1 \\
4^{-13}\equiv 4^{14}
$$
Then note that 
$$ 4^{-1} \equiv 5 $$ so
$$
5^{13} \equiv 4^{14} \\
24^{13} \equiv 23^{14}
$$ 
and finnaly use Fermat as you have done above to increase the exponents by $18$.